# I downloaded and installed linux bash profile and it completely changed my terminal. How do I switch back to the profile I had before?

Tags: linux, xcode, bash

I am taking an online class, and as a part of the instructions, I downloaded and installed a bash profile in my linux command line:

```
curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/flatiron-school/dotfiles/master/.bash_profile -o ~/.bash_profile
source ~/.bash_profile
xcode-select --install
```

Now it is not finding the commands and packages I've used before.

I am also learning other tools, and I need to have it restored. What is the way to "undo" the changes?

Going forward, can I create a virtual environment and install the bash profile for this class in that virtual environment?

Comment: In the general case, if you don't have backups or other arrangements, there is no way to get back a file you removed.  Not a programming question, anyway; voting to close.

Comment: In the specific case, the question is this: Can my bash profile be restored once XCode has messed with it? I.e. does XCode at least back up my bash profile somewhere before ruining it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I restored by renaming the one of the original bash profiles backup files that were in my home directory and re-run it:

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

It is working now.